# MSAL - Client auth - persistent authentication

Tags: token, msal.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for the right approach to connect a 365 identity to a backend service that works on behalf of me in MS Graph.

I have searched a ton of articles, but all I find which is good enough details is stuff that requires admin concent not the client /me namespace

I can get a client token but my issue is to renew the client token automatically because it only lasts for x time.

I use Node.JS as backend..

Any ideas / direction?

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Get access on behalf of a user " flow , follow the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service , hope this will be helpful to you , let us know if your have any concern.

[image]

Microsoft Graph exposes application permissions for apps that call Microsoft Graph under their own identity (Microsoft Graph also exposes delegated permissions for apps that call Microsoft Graph on behalf of a user).
please check doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#2-configure-permissions-for-microsoft-graph

For more detailed information about the permissions available with Microsoft Graph, see the - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

[image]

Comment: No that was not what I needed that's application permissions I need to know how to use delegate permissions - but persist the connection to the user..

Comment: In that case , you need to choose delegated permission instead of application. please check the docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#2-configure-permissions-for-microsoft-graph .